# Casting generic type "as T" whilst enforcing the type of T

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I'm missing a trick here I think and can't believe I've never done this before. However, how can I cast a generic type using the as keyword?

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class SessionManager<T> where T : ISessionManager
{

    protected SessionManager() { }

    public static T GetInstance(HttpSessionState session)
    {

        // Ensure there is a session Id
        if (UniqueId == null)
        {
            UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        // Get the object from session
        T manager = session[UniqueId] as T;
        if (manager == null)
        {
            manager = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            session[UniqueId] = manager;
        }

        return manager;

    }

    protected static string UniqueId = null;

}
```

The line `T manager = session[UniqueId] as T;` throws the following error:

> The type parameter 'T' cannot be used
>   with the 'as' operator because it does
>   not have a class type constraint nor a
>   'class' constraint

Now, I think understand the reason for this; I've not physically told the compiler that T is a class. If I replace:

```
public abstract class SessionManager<T> where T : ISessionManager
```

with

```
public abstract class SessionManager<T> where T : class
```

... then the code builds successfully.

But my question is thus; how can I have both the class and ISessionManager enforcements on the generic type? I'm hoping there's a very simple answer for this.

**EDIT:**
Just to add I had tried: `where T : ISessionManager, class`, turns out I hadn't read my compiler error properly. Simply enough, just putting class before `ISessionManager` fixes the issue. The error I hadn't read was:

> "The 'class' or 'struct' constraint
>   must come before any other
>   constraints".

Dumb moment over.

Comment: BTW, you should not use `CreateInstance<T>` here. You should add a `new()` constraint and simply use `new T()` in code.

Comment: Never knew that! Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
... where T : class, ISessionManager
```

In case you want to use the where `keyword` on methods here is an example that also uses generics

```
    public void store<T>(T value, String key)
    {
        Session[key] = value;
    }

    public T retrieve<T>(String key) where T:class
    {
        return  Session[key] as T ;
    }
```

Comment: Ar**. I've been writing where T : ISessionManager, class!

Answer (score 15):

```
where T : class, ISessionManager
```

you can go even further

```
where T : class, ISessionManager, new()
```

this will force non abstract class with parameterless ctor to be handed in as T

Answer (score 4):

Read up on [Constraints on Type Parameters in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

In this particular case, you must ensure that T is a class:

```
public abstract class SessionManager<T>
    where T : class, ISessionManager
```

Comment: That won't build. ;) class has to come first. Plus, all of the constraints for a particular type must be specified in a single where clause...