# Ways to cast objects to a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

In relation to [Casting generic type "as T" whilst enforcing the type of T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721741/casting-generic-type-as-t-whilst-enforcing-the-type-of-t)

And with the following example

```
private static T deserialize<T>(string streng) where T : class
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(streng);
    return ser.Deserialize(reader) as T;
}
```

and

```
private static T deserialize<T>(string streng)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(streng);
    return (T)ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I'm used to doing the `object as Type` casting, so I was a little confused when I found that I couldn't just do that with `T`. Then I found the question above and in that a solution to the `as T` compiler error.

But why is `where T : class` necessary when using `object as T` and not when using `(T)object`?
What is the actual difference between the two ways of casting the object?

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks abatishchev. Much neater without the namespaces :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `as` implies the cast could fail **and return null**. Without a `: class`, `T` could be `int` etc - which can't be `null`. With `(T)obj` it will simply explode in a shower of sparks; no need to handle a `null`.

As an aside (re `struct`), note you **can** use `as` if it is known you are casting to a `Nullable<>` - for example:

```
static T? Cast<T>(object obj) where T : struct
{
    return obj as T?;
}
```

Comment: That's very informative. I would accept your answer, but the system tells me to wait eight minutes.

Comment: MSDN documentation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=VS.100).aspx (for further reading)

Answer (score 2):

Casting with "as" is specified to 1) perform the cast if it can, and 2) return `null` if it can't.  This is problematic with an unconstrained generic parameter (your second example), because T could possibly be a value type (like `int`), variables of which cannot hold `null`.

When your generic parameter is constrained to be a reference type (with the `class` constraint), the compiler can reason about your type a little more and understand that `null` will always be a valid value for type T.  Therefore, the "as"-style cast can be safely used.

Answer (score 1):

As far as operator `as` returns `null` in failure case, variable should be a class or nullable struct:

Meanwhile `cast` requires nothing like that and you can cast struct on struct.

Answer (score 1):

`(T)obj` throws if `obj` isn't convertible to `T`. You should use `(T)obj` if you're certain that the conversion will work.

And use `as` to replace a test with `is` followed by a cast. Of course T needs to be nullable(either a reference type or a `Nullable<T>`) since `as` returns null on failure. The typical pattern is:

```
T x=y as T;
if(x!=null)
  DoSomething(x);
```

Another difference is that `as` only works for a subset of conversions. Overloaded casts etc will be ignored.

Comment: note: since `Deserialize` returns `object`, other conversions don't apply anyway

Comment: Yes, and in this case he should use the `(T)x` cast anyways, since he knows that the result is of type `T`.